# Inno Setup -- cannot see drive combobox

Tags: inno-setup

I want to see the drives combobox so users can choose which drive to install on.

But when I run install I don't see the combobox at all?

Maybe someone can see what's wrong with this code? I copied it from another website but it just doesn't show the drive combobox therefore I can't select the drive to install on.

Here is my code:

```
var
// combo box for drives
cbDrive : TComboBox ;
// array fo string that keep the drive letters
DrvLetters: array of String;

function GetDriveType( lpDisk: String ): Integer;
external 'GetDriveTypeA@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function GetLogicalDriveStrings( nLenDrives: LongInt; lpDrives: String ): Integer;
external 'GetLogicalDriveStringsA@kernel32.dll stdcall';

const
  DRIVE_UNKNOWN = 0; // The drive type cannot be determined.
  DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR = 1; // The root path is invalid. For example, no volume is mounted at the path.
  DRIVE_REMOVABLE = 2; // The disk can be removed from the drive.
  DRIVE_FIXED = 3; // The disk cannot be removed from the drive.
  DRIVE_REMOTE = 4; // The drive is a remote (network) drive.
  DRIVE_CDROM = 5; // The drive is a CD-ROM drive.
  DRIVE_RAMDISK = 6; // The drive is a RAM disk.


// function to convert disk type to string
function DriveTypeString( dtype: Integer ): String ;
begin
  case dtype of
    DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR : Result := 'Root path invalid';
    DRIVE_REMOVABLE : Result := 'Removable';
    DRIVE_FIXED : Result := 'Fixed';
    DRIVE_REMOTE : Result := 'Network';
    DRIVE_CDROM : Result := 'CD-ROM';
    DRIVE_RAMDISK : Result := 'Ram disk';
  else
    Result := 'Unknown';
  end;
end;

// change folder accordigly to the drive letter selected
procedure cbDriveOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := DrvLetters[ cbDrive.ItemIndex ] + UpperCase(ExpandConstant('{#MyAppName}'));
end;

procedure FillCombo();
var
  n: Integer;
  drivesletters: String; lenletters: Integer;
  drive: String;
  disktype, posnull: Integer;
  sd: String;

begin
  //get the system drive
  sd := UpperCase(ExpandConstant('{sd}'));

  //get all drives letters of system
  drivesletters := StringOfChar( ' ', 64 );
  lenletters := GetLogicalDriveStrings( 63, drivesletters );
  SetLength( drivesletters , lenletters );

  drive := '';
  n := 0;
  while ( (Length(drivesletters) > 0) ) do
  begin
    posnull := Pos( #0, drivesletters );
  if posnull > 0 then
  begin
      drive:= UpperCase( Copy( drivesletters, 1, posnull - 1 ) );

      // get number type of disk
      disktype := GetDriveType( drive );

      // add it only if it is not a floppy
      if ( not ( disktype = DRIVE_REMOVABLE ) ) then
      begin

    cbDrive.Items.Add( drive + '   [' + DriveTypeString( disktype ) + ']' )

        SetArrayLength(DrvLetters, N+1);
        DrvLetters[n] := drive;

        // default select C: Drive
        //if ( Copy(drive,1,2) = 'C:' ) then cbDrive.ItemIndex := n;
        // or default to system drive
        if ( Copy(drive,1,2) = sd ) then cbDrive.ItemIndex := n;

        n := n + 1;
      end

    drivesletters := Copy( drivesletters, posnull+1, Length(drivesletters));
  end
  end;

  cbDriveOnClick( cbDrive );

end;


procedure InitializeWizard();
begin

// create the combo box for drives
cbDrive:= TComboBox.Create(WizardForm.SelectDirPage);
    with cbDrive do
    begin
      Parent := WizardForm.DirEdit.Parent;

      Left := WizardForm.DirEdit.Left;
      Top := WizardForm.DirEdit.Top + WizardForm.DirEdit.Height * 2;
      Width := WizardForm.DirEdit.Width;

      Style := csDropDownList;
    end;

// hide the Browse button
WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.Visible := true;

// Edit box for folder don't have to be editable
WizardForm.DirEdit.Enabled := true;

// fill combo box with Drives
FillCombo;

// set the event on combo change
cbDrive.OnClick := @cbDriveOnClick ;
end;

procedure MyAfterInstall2(FileName: String);
begin
  MsgBox('Just installed ' + FileName + ' as ' + CurrentFileName + '.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. At least in Unicode version of Inno Setup, once I make the code compatible with the Unicode version by:

- Adding missing `;` after `end` before  `drivesletters := Copy( drivesletters, posnull+1, Length(drivesletters));`
- Using Unicode version of `GetDriveType` and `GetLogicalDriveStrings` by replacing `A@` with `W@`.

[image]

Comment: I made those changes but now am getting an Out of Range runtime error on this line:WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := DrvLetters[ cbDrive.ItemIndex ] + UpperCase(ExpandConstant('{#MyAppName}'));

Comment: In your screen shot I see the text "Where should My Program be installed?" I don't see that text in my code.

Comment: That's a standard contents of `SelectDirPage`, where your code adds the combo box. + Are you using the Unicode version of Inno Setup?

Comment: I don't know if I am using the Unicode ver or not. How can I tell?

Comment: It should say (a) or (u) in the window title. Or check the About box.

Comment: It says (a) in the title. So how do I get the (u) ver?

Comment: I installed the (u) version but I still do not see the combobox.

Comment: I've given up on using Inno. I've switched to another install program. Thanks for your help.